# Change percent sign in iterm

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

I use iterm2 for my daily work. How I can change the `%` sign or `~` to the cool character like `#` or maybe something like this `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`? :)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I wish I could help more, but you may find this helpful [How to format the path in a zsh prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/49092/how-to-format-the-path-in-a-zsh-prompt)

My prompt looks nothing like that, and I'm a little unclear on what the % at the far right actually represents. I've seen it before, but I've only been learning bash/zsh for mere months :/

Why the heck would you want `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` as a prompt?

Mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRcoE.png)

Comment: look nice in the screenshot, can you write down a way to achieve the exact style?

Comment: Sorry, that was my terminal tears ago and I haven't been using the terminal as much in my job for the last 5 years or so. I'm pretty sure most of that came from zsh profiles that were built into ohmyzsh but not positive.